# How to call and wait async function done inside sync function in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to call and wait async function done before return from a sync function

```
// async function
Future<User> getUser(String username) async {
   ...
}
```

In dart, i could use https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-cli/waitFor.html to wait a async function before go to next statement.

```
bool checkUser(String username, String encodedPwd) {
    var user = waitFor<User>(getUser(username));
    if (user.pwd == encodedPwd) 
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

Because the require of the framework, the checkUser function will be call by framework, and must be a sync function.

In flutter, I could not use dart:cli, I implement by pattern .then()  .whenComplete(), but when call checkUser the statement print(1) will be call and end the function without wait for getUser finish.

```
bool checkUser(String username, String pwd) {
  getUser(username).then((user) { 
     if (user.pwd == encodePwd(pwd)) {
        return true;
     } else {
        return false;
     }
 );
 print(1);
}
```

My question is how to call async function inside sync function and wait the async function done before return.

Thank you.

Comment: The function `getUser()` is a Future. So obviously the sync statement `print(1)` will be executed first.

Comment: if you need to wait for a async function to complete you need to use `await` , and you can only use the `await` inside an async function, i guess you are thinking of some over engineering here

Answer (score 1):

Being able to do what you ask would basically render the distinction between sync and async functions useless (and block the main thread I think). The function you linked *"should be considered a last resort"*.

I think what you want is :

```
Future<bool> checkUser(String username, String pwd) async { 
  var user = await getUser(username); 
  return user.pwd == encodePwd(pwd) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating a task, then waiting/yielding for the task to complete.  The Yield prevents blocking.

```
    var result = MyAsyncMethod.InvokeAsync(data);
    result.Start();

    while (result.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
    }
```